# Change type of Datastore field to Text from String?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I can't seem to do this. The list that the app engine datastore viewer does not contain Text as an option. I had to change my fields because some of my values were too long for String, but now I can't retroactively fix my old entries.

Answer (score 3):

To change the property type used by the old entities, you need to manually update each of them.

This can be easily and efficiently accomplished using the [mapper API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/).  [This guide](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython) explains how to use this API.

You may also want to read [this blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Exploring-the-new-mapper-API) by [Nick Johnson](http://blog.notdot.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to fix your old entries. The old ones should work as is, and the new ones just won't be indexed.

See 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/282dc825f9c46684 .